# Creating vertical scrollbar

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flex2

I want to create a vertical scrollbar in such a way that we can do the following:

1. Change the color of the arrow icons of the scrollbar.
2. Change the background color of the arrow icons of the scrollbar.
3. Change the TrackColor of the scrollbar.
4. Change the ThumbColor of the scrollbar.

Comment: @MaheshParate Looking at the tags, it would seem he needs a non-Spark solution.

Comment: @RIAstar:- i have removed comment didn't checked for tag... yes it says non-spark...

Comment: What have you tried; and what problems have you experienced while doing this?  Also, it may halp if you specify which version of Flex you're using.